# What i need to read in order to configure PowerDNS?

Tags: domain-name-system, powerdns

Recently i was tasked to configure PowerDNS on windows using Microsoft SQL data source so it will resolve LAN names like "a1" into 192.168.0.10, "a2" into 192.168.0.11 etc. Lots of records. But i don't have experience with DNS server configuration, and there is no "noice" information in PowerDNS manual. Basically, all manual states is "put DNS data into SQL table". And "DNS data" is cryptic records with columns like "domain_id", "type" and fields like "A", "AAA", "SOA" and so on. I have tried to enter some simple data into database and was gifted with exception in powerDNS :). It seems i must enter **correct** data according to some rules.

The question is: where can i read introductory information about PowerDNS configuration for LAN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really strongly suggest you picking up a solid understanding of DNS prior to doing this...

Comment: Yep. So, is it any introductory information available? :)

Comment: Wikipedia is a good start: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System
Also, it's a little dry, but the DNS & Bind O'Reilly book is a pretty solid resource.